# How to play .ts files? (and other unusual formats)

Tags: 10.04, codecs

How can i play **.ts**  files in Ubuntu? I would prefer if you could recommend a codec instead of a new piece of software, so I can use any software to play.

And is there any codec pack that make me sure I will be able to play all ordinary media files? Something similar to k-lite codec pack.

**note:** some of my .ts files already can be played with SMplay, but just some...

**PS:**
as i mentioned above i already can play some .ts files. and i have *ubuntu-restricted-extras* and *mplayer* and *samplayer* in latest version. the problem is that some .ts files that open in windows systems do not play in my ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend smplayer and gecko-mediaplayer, which are the best mplayer frontend and browser plugin respectively. For codecs get `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. I also recommend the [Comprehensive Multimedia & Video Howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=766683) tutorial.

## [smplayer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/smplayer) [image: Install smplayer]

## [gecko-mediaplayer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gecko-mediaplayer) [image: Install gecko-mediaplayer]

## [ubuntu-restricted-extras](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-restricted-extras) [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras]

Comment: It's possible (if it's legal to do so) that you need to install libdvdcss from the Medibuntu repository.  Follow the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu, then do a sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2

Comment: i installed packages referenced in Howto (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=766683) and now they can be played with SMplayer. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome @takpar. Never had any video codec problems since I started to use that tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution then, install `mplayer-nogui` and play your video from terminal.

## [mplayer-nogui](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mplayer-nogui) [image: Install mplayer-nogui]

**Playing video from terminal:**

```
mplayer /path/to/your/video/file
```

Almost all the videos can be played here. None of the videos failed for me but I have never tried .ts video files. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Smplayer can play this type of videos but you cannot rewind or fast forward.
You can only watch it.
I run Linux Mint 17 and all multimedia files play normally except .ts files which play in Smplayer only.
I have installed the following packages
ubuntu-restricted-extras - Smplayer which are not installed by default in Linux Mint 17.
I hope this can help.
Edited from this point :)
I do a work around to solve this issue
I use WinFF app to convert the .ts file to any other file that play normally which in my case I prefer the following settings in winff ( sorry I am not allowed to upload images to illustrate the description provided )

Convert to : ( I choose DVD )
Preset ( I select PAL DVD fast LQ)

Preset settings can change according to your needs of course :)
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely arising from the fact that some files are encrypted and in such a cases, they will play on windows, but not ubuntu, and there is little we can (or should) do about that.

Answer (score 0):

.ts is actually .mpg.  To me (Ubuntu 12.04), totem can play .ts video file after I've renamed the file from .ts to .mpg...

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are like me and use VLC and also having problems:
Isolating the .ts file from the .srt (subtitle) file in a different folder made the trick for me.